# RViz segfaults when adding second display plugin

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-groovy, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a freshly installed Groovy RViz (with default config) generates numerous duplicating warnings during the start:

```
[ INFO] [1357462354.607319704]: pluginlib WARNING: PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS is deprecated, please use PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS instead. You can run the script 'plugin_macro_update' provided with pluginlib in your package source folder to automatically and recursively update legacy macros.
```

And then when I try to add **any two** displays from the following list: *Camera*, *Image* or *DepthCloud* (I didn't try many of other available though) RViz segfaults with the error in system log:

```
rviz[8091] general protection ip:7fb48e2571be sp:7fffbd57fea0 error:0 in libclass_loader.so[7fb48e226000+4a000]
```

Same happens when I try to delete one of the listed above displays.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Boris

---

**UPDATE**: Opened a [ticket](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/559) for segfault problem.

Regarding the PLUGIN_DECLARE_CLASS. It seems to be related to segfault, but I didn't realize that before changing default log level to DEBUG. [Here](http://pastebin.com/vJTFN2bD) what happens from RViz perspective.

So, should I still open a separate ticket or add new info to the previous one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51543/rviz-segfaults-when-adding-second-display-plugin/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2013-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm working on this, see github issue:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/559#issuecomment-11975277

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-01-18**:
Thanks for the fix! Side question though -- when the changes usually pushed to main repository from `ros-shadow-fixed`?

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-01-25**:
Did not see this...it varies but usually we go through a build cycle in less than 24 hours.. Usually when I release code by early evening the turnover is completed by morning. You can see the status on jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080...when all packages have completed building, they are then synced to

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-01-25**:
...shadow-fixed. There is a period of time after all packages have built on jenkins to the time they are synced on shadow-fixed. In other words, just because all packages are built on jenkins doesn't mean that you can do a sudo apt-get update/upgrade right away. If packages fail to build on jenkins

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-01-25**:
...the sync does not happen.